# Execute jar in jsp page - wait until jar execution is completed

Tags: java, jsp, jar, execution

I have a jar file that is required to be run on the jsp page. 
jar file is designed to be executed in the command line. This is my code:

```
public static String scheduleCourses() throws IOException {

    String execute = "java -jar execute.jar \"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db\" root \"\" file.txt";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execute);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    try {
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(widgets.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return "Error with import<br>" +ex;
    }
    return "All done";
}
```

but somehow, although, this function is being executed, it stops in like 10-20 seconds.But if I run the jar file from the command prompt - it works just fine

Comment: I would add that its considered bad practice to perform actions like this in the jsp as it is extremly hard to debug. Run the jar in its own servlet, attach what ever output your trying to get from the jar to the request then forward to the jsp to produce the final output to the requestor. This makes for much better modularity and easier debugging since java error will throw more meaningful errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the solution above.